# download_file using boto3 - getting file not found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Trying the following code:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname("some/relative/path/for/saving")):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("some/relative/path/for/saving"))
s3_client.download_file("s3.my.bucket",
                        "some/relative/path/ending/with/e365e14b-afd8-4e52-9457-cad42bb638f3.csv",
                        "some/relative/path/for/saving/test.csv")
```

Getting: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'some/relative/path/for/saving/test.csv.DE69D8cb'`

with wired added DE69D8cb

Note:
Running:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname("some/relative/path/for/saving")):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("some/relative/path/for/saving"))
s3_client.download_file("s3.my.bucket",
                        "some/relative/path/ending/with/e365e14b-afd8-4e52-9457-cad42bb638f3.csv",
                        "not_hierarchical_path.csv")
```

works.

saw few complains regarding this but didn't had luck to see proper explanation\solution.

Any suggestions?

SOLVED

added / in the end of the paths
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname("some/relative/path/for/saving/")):
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("some/relative/path/for/saving/"))

Comment: Does the `some/relative/path/for/saving/` directory exist?

Comment: yes, added ensuring in the question also

Comment: Might be worth trying `./some/relative/path/for/saving/test.csv` as your filename

Comment: same error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './some/relative/path/for/saving/test.csv.c3815e79'

Comment: That error implies you are missing a '/' after the '.' in the path

Comment: still happens - it it a typo in the previous comment

Comment: @ALjazzguitar Please add the Solution as an Answer, instead of putting it in the Question. This will help future readers. Congrats for figuring it out!